# Can a tractor beam be altered to push instead of pull?

Tags: star-wars

Within the Star Wars universe, suppose for some reason a ship's goal is to move something aside of or away from the craft rather than draw it in - could it be done with the tractor beam?

Note that this may have happened in other franchises, but I'm not sure about **in Star Wars**?

Comment: It certainly can [in Star Trek](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsor_beam)

Comment: A beam used for pushing is called a [pressor beam](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/93). I don't know if the same beam generator can generate both tractor and pressor beams. I guess it depends on whose made-up science you're talking about.

Comment: Given that The Empire uses a tractor beam to maneuver Tantive IV into the Star Destroyer and The Millennium Falcon into The Death Star, some pushing must be involved once they have the ship where they want it. I don't know of any examples of pure reverse tractoring in Star Wars.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsor_beam

Answer (score 4):

### A tractor beam pulls things, a repulsor beam pushes things.

It appears that the term "tractor beam" evolved from the term "attractor beam", which clearly suggests that the beam is used to pull one object towards another.

> A tractor beam is a device with the ability to attract one object to another from a distance.  The concept originates in fiction: the term was coined by E. E. Smith (an update of his earlier "attractor beam") in his novel Spacehounds of IPC (1931).
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractor_beam)

The word "tractor" itself was originally meant to describe the act of pulling something, not pushing it.  [It is derived from the Latin word *trahō*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/traho#Latin), which means "to drag".  The same root word, *trahō*, is the source of our words "drag", "draw [towards]", and "track [i.e., follow]".

Although there are similar beams used to push objects, they are technically referred to as "repulsor beams" or "pressor beams":

> Less commonly, a similar beam that repels is called a pressor beam or repulsor beam. Gravity impulse and gravity propulsion beams are traditionally areas of research from fringe physics that coincide with the concepts of tractor and repulsor beams.
>   -  [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractor_beam)

In the *Star Wars* universe, these rules seem to apply - if a beam pulls things, it is a [tractor beam](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tractor_beam);  if it pushes things, it is a [repulsor beam](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsor_beam).

From the links to Wookieepedia above:

> **Tractor Beam:**  A tractor beam was a projected force-field used by spaceports, planetary bases, space stations, and starships to effectively grasp and guide vessels to a safe designated landing. They could also be used to forcibly capture enemy ships. The first Death Star was equipped with 768 tractor beam generators, enabling it to constrain ships such as the Millennium Falcon with ease.
>
> **Repulsor Beam:**  A repulsor beam was a focused energy beam that the Verpine used to prevent collisions between their colony asteroids and space debris. They created a repulsorfield shell; when two shells came in contact they ricocheted harmless away from each other.

Comment: Yes, big bold headers always make an answer look better ;-) +1

Comment: Only the final paragraph (and quote) seem relevant.

Comment: @Richard - I like the whole thing.  Feel free to add your own answer, of course.